# Cycle application windows changed in recent update (2019)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, window-manager, mission-control

I am used to pressing `CMD`+ `` ` `` on my mac to cycle through windows of the same application.

In recent updates, I am not sure if this was when updating to Mojave, maybe later, maybe before, this behavoiur changed.

I have 3 windows of an IDE (PhpStorm) and I used to be able to cycle reliably and predictably through them, similar to how you cycle between apps with `CMD`+`TAB`, but this behaviour is now very broken (or I don't understand it anymore)

It seems to choose a random window every time I press the combination instead of simply going the previously opened window.

Has anybody else noticed this? Can someone explain to me what is the logic behind? so I can wrap my brain around it and perhaps be agile again :p

ps. I mentioned my IDE because IDEs tend to overwrite OS shortcuts, so I am only about 90% sure it is macOs's fault, but it could be the IDE's fault.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Did you verify the behavior by reproducing it with other 1st party and 3rd party apps?

Comment: Are all your instances in the same Space? Spaces down't like to be spread one app to multiple Spaces... it breaks things.

Comment: mmhm, strange.. @Tetsujin yes, they are in the same space. -> nimesh I only tried with finder (I have no other apps that I use with multiple windows) and it works fine.
The strange thing about he IDE is that it is similar to a web browser taht it has tabs inside and all, so behaviour changes on some shortcuts...
I was able to add a custom shortcut inside the IDE, but I am not 100% sure if that is what I should be doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use PhpStorm 2019.2 on macOS 10.14.6 Mojave. The behavior/logic for `` CMD + ` `` is not any different from how it has been in any relatively recent version of macOS or PhpStorm.

Pressing `` CMD + ` `` switches to the most recently used window, unless you haven't done anything in the currently active window, in which case it switches to the next most recently opened window (and this pattern continues for however many windows you have open).

For example, let's say you have a file open in PhpStorm in window A, then open another file in window B, and finally a third file in window C. If you're working in window C and then press `` CMD + ` ``, you'll be switched to window B. If you press `` CMD + ` `` again before doing anything else, you'll be switched to window A. However, if, instead, you work on the file in window B first, then when you press `` CMD + ` ``, you'll be switched back to window C (the most recently open window). In order to reach window A, you must press `` CMD + ` `` twice without doing anything in the window that comes up after the first window switch.

Comment: __unless you haven't done anything in the currently active window__ that! that is what I noticed, the anoying part is, sometimes I am jumping back and forth between two but only using the editor in one of them... this is where I thought the logic had changed, but well, tha is as good an explanation as I plan to get, thanks!